# How to create square grids using plotly, mapbox, python?

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox

So I'm trying to create a square grid based map to be displayed on Dash, using plotly.

I have the informations of latitude and longitude of all 4 points per square, as well as the polygon shapes.

Does anybody know how to to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to do something like the following.
[image: 1]

This is a chloropleth map built using the mapbox-plotly API. In order to build something like this you have to create custom geojson file.

https://developer.here.com/blog/an-introduction-to-geojson

This geojson file then has to paired with a dataframe that contains the linkage between the geojson file and the information you want to display respective to that coordinate polygon.

https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/